# How to combine docker build and docker run into one command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There is a `Dockerfile` in the current directory. Initially we could:

1. `docker build` to build the image
2. make use of the built image to `docker run` to start the corresponding docker container

But often times there is need to update the `Dockerfile`. As a result, there would be the following steps to restart the docker container with the latest update

1. `docker build` to build the image again
2. kill/stop the running docker container
3. remove the *image*
4. `docker run` to start the docker container again with the updated docker image

But there are 4 steps involved =>

**Question: How to minimize the 4 steps above, e.g. rebuild the docker image and restart the updated container in one go like the `docker-compose up --build <sevice_name>`**

Comment: With a `Makefile` maybe?

Comment: I don't think Make is the right tool here (how would you express the file dependencies to restart the container?) but this seems like a simple enough shell script, or a basic Compose setup as hinted here.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple script that will trigger an action once a watched file get modified.

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76708102/11301941).

What you can do in this case, is simply write a small bash script with the 4 steps needed. and add it to be executed to the script whenever the `dockerfile` change occurs.

An alternative solution to reduce this commands series, `docker-compse` can be a good option as the `docker-compose down` command will stop containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by the `docker-compose up` command.

Lastley, as suggested in the comments, You can use `makefile` which defines a set of commands to run and the make utility runs them.

Comment: The question came out in light of the `docker-compose` command's `docker-compose up --build <service_name>`. So similarly I wonder if it is possible to use `docker` command also to `build` and `run` in one go

Comment: I dont believe there is a docker-supported option for this, My guess is its only possible with docker commands using the makefile. And am not even familiar with the `makefile` that's what I get with the fast reading about.